# Something wrong with my PHP form Key class

Tags: php, oop

I'm following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/secure-your-forms-with-form-keys--net-4753) to try and make a PHP Form Key Validation script. For some reason, my constructor is not creating a value for my `$old_formKey` variable.

The tutorial mentions that Singletons are more secure, but it doesn't go into the implementation. I know basic principles of OOP with Java, but I don't know much about PHP OOP Principles. I was just trying to wing it by making the class variables static--and I think this is where my problem is. However, when my constructor is called, it is supposed to give `$old_formKey` the value of `$_POST[form_key]` "if isset()"

I am not able to get the constructor to place the value of the old formKey in the desired variable space.

So this is where I'm having problems.

```
<?php
class formKey
{
    private static $formKey;

    private static $old_formKey;

    public function validate()
    {
        echo $_POST['form_key'];
        //We use the old formKey and not the new generated version
        if($_POST['form_key'] == $old_formKey) {
            //The key is valid, return true.
            return true;
        }
        else {
            //The key is invalid, return false.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

My formKey validation script looks something like this.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    //Validate the form key
    if(!isset($_POST['form_key']) || !$formKey->validate()) {
        //Form key is invalid, show an error
        $error_msg = 'Security Error.';
        $die = "die";
    }
    else {
        /*continue validation*/
    } 
}
?>
```

The script returns the error message and then displays it because `$old_formKey` is never given a value inside of the `validate()` method.

For some reason, I cannot modify the class variable from within the `validate()` method. Sorry if this has been addressed before. I honestly looked and couldn't find it!

```
function __construct()
{
    //We need the previous key so we store it
    if(isset($_SESSION['form_key']))
    {
        self::$old_formKey = $_SESSION['form_key'];
    }
}
```

Sorry I forgot to include my constructor. It has been added above.

Comment: **12 Jun 2009** danger any 7 year old tutorial is bound to be dangerously out of date

Comment: To implement a singleton variable, you would use `self` since it's static. You also have to assign it `self::$old_formKey = 'whatever';` Same with `$formKey`. That being said, even how you have it, you have not assigned `$old_formKey ` any value.

Comment: Also you are saying *"when my constructor is called..."*, do you mean `__construct()`? If so you don't have one, at least from the example you've posted.

Comment: I would just use a normal variable, not static. There is no advantage that I can see:  `private $old_formKey;`, `$this->old_formKey = $_SESSION['form_key'];`, `if($_POST['form_key'] == $this->old_formKey)`

Comment: That tutorial is bogus, anyone claiming _creating singletons is a more advanced OOP topic_ should stop writing tutorials immediately ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already wrote as a comment, the tutorial you mentioned like *Dagon* wrote, is out of date, second its completely bogus.

This has nothing to do with *validating* a form, the focus on this topic is **identifying** the form.

You generate a unique identifier key which is generated by the server (this case PHP) in order to keep track of the forms state. If the unique *key* changes in which it will be different from the *key* stored by the server, the form can be rejected where it cannot be identified (this doesn't mean at all that the form is *not* valid).

The tutorial uses an Object Orientated approach, so I will respect that. The following steps are being made

1. Generate a unique *key* and store it in the users (or visitors, depends on the terminology here; I'll describe them as `users` from now on) `SESSION`
2. Output the *key* in a form
3. Identify the form on submit and compare the *(unidentified) key* against the *(identified) key(s)* stored in the `SESSION`

   4.1. Validate form when identity is met

   4.2. Reject form if unable to identify

Starting with the generation of an instance, the layout of the class is pretty simple, it doesn't need to be a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) nor should it contain anything *statically*.

The base of the class can be divided in three sections, *creation*, *storing* and *identifying*.

```
class FormIdentifier {

  const CONTAINER_KEYSPACE = 'form_keys';

  /**
   * Generate a key
   * @return string
   */
  public function generateKey() {
    // you can use any complicated mumbo-jumbo to generate a key instead
    $key = uniqid();
    // store it
    $this->storeKey($key);
    // return for use, e.g. in a form
    return $key;
  }

  /**
   * Store a key into users session
   */
  protected function storeKey($key) {
    session_start();
      $_SESSION[self::CONTAINER_KEYSPACE][] = $key;
    session_write_close();
  }

  /**
   * Identifies a key against the keys in the users stored session.
   * @return true if identified, false otherwise
   */
  public function identifyKey($key) {
    session_start();
      if( ($found = search_array($key, $_SESSION[self::CONTAINER_KEYSPACE])) !== false ) {
        unset($_SESSION[self::CONTAINER_KEYSPACE][$found]);
        session_write_close();
        return true;
      } 

    session_write_close();
    return false;
  }
}
```

To generate a key, we're not going to mix HTML output with classes and methods. `FormIdentifier`s purpose is solely *creating*, *storing* and *identifying* form keys, nothing else. So an example to use in a form

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php (new FormIdentifier)->generateKey() ?>" />
</form>
```

You may also store the returned *key* somewhere and use it in a different fashion, whatever suites your needs.

```
<?php $key = (new FormIdentifier)->generateKey(); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?= $key ?>" />
```

To identify (and eventually validate) the form, you can specify the forms posted *key* and compare it against the key(s) stored in the users session. The structure used here is most likely to show the user some notification for a key mismatch. It entirely depends on how you wish to implement this step, you can wrap it in a function or even combine it with the class `FormIdentifier`.

```
/**
 * Simple if/else, a POST was made so act on `form_key`s presence only
 */
if($_POST && array_key_exists('form_key', $_POST)) {  
  if((new FormIdentifier)->identifyKey($_POST['form_key')) {
    // identity was verified  
    // validate your form
    $fv = new FormValidator($_POST);
    // or whatever ..
    $fv->validate();
  }
  else {
    // unable to determine identity
    // do something silly ..
  }
}
```

**some notes**

- None of the supplied code was tested
- It is important to realise that the [presentation logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_logic) should be separated from all steps made here.
- Stop reading tutorials **older** than 2 years! If the author doesn't mind updating its stuff, then don't mind reading it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't wait to try this.

Comment: People who downvote without leaving a comment should banned from this site periodly ..

Answer (score 1):

Extend the formKey class?

```
class B extend formKey{
    public function validate($formKey, $oldFormKey)
    {
        return $formKey == $oldFormKey;
    }
}
```

call it like this

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $oldFormKey = "abc";
    $formKey = new B();
    if (!isset($_POST['form_key']) 
        || !$formKey->validate($_POST['form_key'], $oldFormKey)) {
        //Form key is invalid, show an error
        $error_msg = 'Security Error.';
        $die = "die";
    } else {
        //continue validation 
    } 
}
```

It may be useful for you, and, I'm curious about "For some reason, I cannot modify the class variable from within the validate() method"

Answer (score 1):

To make your variables come through the object (`__construct()` through to `validate()`), you need to assign them in the class scope, then recall them from the same scope:

```
class formKey
    {
        private $formKey,
                $old_formKey;

        public function __construct()
            {
                // I just set to false as default
                $this->old_formKey = false;
                // Assign here
                if(isset($_SESSION['form_key']))
                    $this->old_formKey = $_SESSION['form_key'];
            }

        public function validate()
            {
                // Use $this-> to recall it from the construct
                return ($_POST['form_key'] == $this->old_formKey);
            }
    }
```

Comment: OOP space? What's that?

Comment: @dbf I mean your scope. You can not assign `$this->var` in one method and try and call it with `$var` in another. You would need to call `$this->var` in the other method to access it.